# Why the class I created in python is not recognizing the attributes set to False?

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn, data-transform

I'm trying to compete on the House Prices - Advanced Regression Techniques Kaggle competition

I'm writing a custom transformer that works seamlessly with Scikit-Learn functionalities that adds combined attributes

the transformer has four hyperparameters (`add_baths, add_bsmt_baths, add_above_grade_baths, add_porch_area`) set to True by default. This hyperparameters will allow me to easily find out whether adding this attributes helps the Machine Learning algorithms or not.

But the problem is that when I set one of these hyperparameters to False, the class still returns me the column as if I set it to True

```
class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def __init__(self, add_baths=True, add_bsmt_baths=True, add_above_grade_baths=True, add_porch_area=True):
            self.add_baths = add_baths
            self.add_bsmt_baths = add_bsmt_baths
            self.add_above_grade_baths = add_above_grade_baths
            self.add_porch_area = add_porch_area
        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            return self
        def transform(self, X):
            X['T_FlrSF'] = X['1stFlrSF'] + X['2ndFlrSF']
            if self.add_baths:
                X['T_Bath'] = X['BsmtFullBath'] + X['BsmtHalfBath'] + X['FullBath'] + X['HalfBath']
            if self.add_bsmt_baths:
                X['T_BsmtBath'] = X['BsmtFullBath'] + X['BsmtHalfBath']
            if self.add_above_grade_baths:
                X['T_agBath'] = X['FullBath'] + X['HalfBath']
            if self.add_porch_area:
                X['T_Porch'] = X['OpenPorchSF'] + X['EnclosedPorch'] + X['3SsnPorch'] + X['ScreenPorch']
            return X

    attr_adder = CombinedAttributesAdder(add_baths=False, add_bsmt_baths=False)
    housing_extra_attribs = attr_adder.transform(housing)
```

Here it is supposed to return all the columns, and because I set the arguments `add_baths=False, add_bsmt_baths=False` It shouldn't create the `T_Bath` nor the `T_BsmtBath` columns

```
housing_extra_attribs.columns

...

 Index(['Id', 'MSSubClass', 'MSZoning', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'Street',
   'Alley', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig',
   'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType',
   'HouseStyle', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd',
   'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType',
   'MasVnrArea', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtQual',
   'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinSF1',
   'BsmtFinType2', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'Heating',
   'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF',
   'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath',
   'HalfBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'KitchenQual',
   'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Functional', 'Fireplaces', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType',
   'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'GarageQual',
   'GarageCond', 'PavedDrive', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF',
   'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'PoolQC',
   'MiscFeature', 'MiscVal', 'MoSold', 'YrSold', 'SaleType',
   'SaleCondition', 'T_FlrSF', 'T_Bath', 'T_BsmtBath', 'T_agBath',
   'T_Porch'],
  dtype='object')
```

Comment: we can't run it so we can't test what makes problems - so we can't help you.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe you have something different then you expect. OR maybe it runs different function then you expect.

Comment: The dataset is from the kaggle competition "House Prices - Advanced Regression Techniques"

Comment: you could add link to this competition (but as I remeber it may need login to kaggle to access data)

Comment: Please take a look at the [mcve] help page. What code is there has at least a SyntaxError due to incorrect formatting; even when fixing the obvious errors, it is not clear how to reproduce the error – please provide some (small) sample input and the code necessary to process it. Ideally, we should be able to copy/paste it directly to run and reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without copying the training data in the transform section you are modyfiying the original training data so if you already transformed it  previously with True attributes  then the columns had been already created earlier.
Please try the following but make sure the training data has not been modified earlier:

```
class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def __init__(self, add_baths=True, add_bsmt_baths=True, add_above_grade_baths=True, add_porch_area=True):
            self.add_baths = add_baths
            self.add_bsmt_baths = add_bsmt_baths
            self.add_above_grade_baths = add_above_grade_baths
            self.add_porch_area = add_porch_area
        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            return self
        def transform(self, X):
            X_=X.copy()
            X_['T_FlrSF'] = X_['1stFlrSF'] + X_['2ndFlrSF']
            if self.add_baths:
                X_['T_Bath'] = X_['BsmtFullBath'] + X_['BsmtHalfBath'] + X_['FullBath'] + X_['HalfBath']
            if self.add_bsmt_baths:
                X_['T_BsmtBath'] = X_['BsmtFullBath'] + X_['BsmtHalfBath']
            if self.add_above_grade_baths:
                X_['T_agBath'] = X_['FullBath'] + X_['HalfBath']
            if self.add_porch_area:
                X_['T_Porch'] = X_['OpenPorchSF'] + X_['EnclosedPorch'] + X_['3SsnPorch'] + X_['ScreenPorch']
            return X_
```

Comment: simple and elegant, just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! I don't know why I didn't come up with this solution, maybe I need more practice